# Show that the intersection of a quadric hypersurface with a hyperplane is a connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

### Problem statement

Let $S$ be the set of points $(w,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ which satisfy both
$$wy+wz-x^2-2xy-y^2+yz+z^2=0$$
and
$$y+z=1$$
subject to the constraints $w,x,y,z\geq 0$. Show that the set $S$ is connected.

### Attempted solution

I have been able to show that the intersection of these hypersurfaces is connected when $x,y,z \geq 0$ and there is no restriction on the sign of $w$. Let $S'$ be the set of points $(w,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ which lie on the intersection of the two hypersurfaces above, but subject only to the constraints $x,y,z\geq 0$. We can eliminate $z$ from the first equation with the substitution $z=1-y$, obtaining
$$1+w =x+(x+y)^2.$$
The points in $S'$ satisfy the above equation with the constraints $x\geq 0$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$. To show that $S'$ is connected, we will show that it is path-connected. That is, for any two arbitrary points $(w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(w_2,x_2,y_2,z_2)$ in $S'$, we will find a continuous function $f(t)$ from $[0,1]$ to $S'$ where $f(0) = (w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $f(1) = (w_2,x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

Define $X(t) = (1-t)x_1 + tx_2$ and $Y(t) = (1-t)y_1 + ty_2$. Then
$$f(t) = \left(X(t)+(X(t)+Y(t))^2-1,X(t),Y(t),1-Y(t)\right)$$
is a valid path connecting $(w_1,x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(w_2,x_2,y_2,z_2)$. We conclude that $S'$ is connected.

### Question

I am having trouble showing that the original set $S$ (i.e., those points in $S'$ which additionally satisfy $w\geq0$) is connected. Might there be a way to amend my path function to restrict its image to the set $S$, or is there perhaps another approach to solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The strip of points $(x,y)$ such that $(w,x,y)$ satisfies those conditions looks like this:
[image]

Your approach of linear interpolation doesn't work because it isn't quite convex. But you can solve that by having a path in $(x,y)$ space that moves along the $y$ axis then along the $x$ axis.